# $dL=dr/ \sin\alpha$. Is it correct according to calculus?

Tags: calculus

[image]

In the book it is written that surface area of a ring element is 
$dA = 2\pi rdr/ \sin a$

I know that by pappus theorem, $dA = 2\pi rdL$.

But here dL = dr/sin a. I am unable to understand this and need some explaining. Can we really do that? What is 'dr' here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

What's written could be interpreted as follows:

[image]